# How to have an android service keep the phonegap ui alive

Tags: java, android, service, cordova

I am working on an android application that uses phonegap/cordova. This app uses a javascript to fetch content from the server from time to time and issues a systemtray alert if there is new content.
The problem I was facing was that the app would eventually just quit when android was short on memory or whatsoever.

So I added a service to my manifest (everybody says a service would solve the problem).

```
<service android:name="UpdateService" />
```

Verywell, but just having this service there does nothing (obviously). So how do I make my service trigger the main application to keep running?

ADDITION:
I also managed to start the service in my main application

Comment: Using javascript in the browser to do background checking is probably the wrong way to go about things.  Do your background checking in an android service in java (using the http request or whatever) and issue the alert from there too.  Only open the browser based javascript when your need an interactive UI, ie, something fitting the Android Actitivy model.

Comment: That would be nice, but the app has to be multiplatform. Therefor I am using phonegap and jquery mobile (ajax) to fetch content. That works in every browser. Phonegap does allow the javascript to run in the background, but the process simply dies.

Comment: Your UI can be multi-platform, but you'll have to accessorize it with platform specific extensions.  Wrap the linkage to your extensions with some javascript code which presents a universal API, so that the rest of your code can be the same on all platforms.  At least to me that seems far preferable than trying to shoehorn something like node.js into an android service to run javascript code in the background in a way that's actually compatible with the Android system (ie, won't die all the time)

Comment: Yes, that makes sense. But since this is my first android app I wanted to keep it simple by using techniques I know (HTML CSS Javascript). But since I wrote all my calls already in JS, I would rather continue this way then starting all over again. I'll use your approach in my next project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try registering a PendingIntent with the AlarmManager that will check to make sure your application is running every n milliseconds.  If it isn't running have the service start your application again.

Use some code like this to start your application:

```
Intent serviceIntent = new Intent("com.myapp.LaunchActivity");
startService(serviceIntent);
```

Replace **com.myapp.LaunchActivity** with your package name and LaunchActivity.

Comment: I will have a look at the AlarmManager and checking for running applications. :)

Comment: I expect this will be rather annoying to the user, assuming it even works while the user is using another app (especially playing a game or watching a video)

Comment: That strikes me as a side effect of the webkit engine being in the same process as this service.  Get a resource hungry foreground app and the whole thing may be killed.  Android might restart the service asap after that, but probably not the activiry code.