# Resuming Android PhoneGap app can cause app to be unresponsive for a long while

Tags: javascript, android, jquery-mobile, cordova-3, cordova-plugins

I've been in contact with Phonegap Support, as well as people who are more experienced in Android than I, as well as a  knowledgeable mobile web app developer to determine why an odd error is occurring in my application. According to the people I have talked to, the problem could stem from any of these places (Android, a PhoneGap plugin, or using jQuery mobile).

Here is the folder containing the index.html that holds my code for the Phonegap app:
https://github.com/galenthomasramos/EcigSurvey/tree/master/platforms/android/assets/www

The target device for this app is a Motorola Razr M. I use a local notification plugin to provide notifications throughout a day. Sometimes upon clicking on a notification, some code within my onResume event function is fired very late. I should receive and alert as soon as I resume the app, but instead I receive the alert almost a minute afterwards. An even bigger problem (same symptoms- very late function calls) occurs when I try to log in to my application (login screen is the first page to appear within my application) where I have entered the password correctly, but the phone will not navigate to the next page. There is no way that the page should just reset and not navigate to the next page-- Either I would be alerted to incorrect user input and asked to try again, or the app should successfully navigate to the next page.

I should mention that these errors seem to only occur when accessing the application via a notification, this does not occur if I resume the app from the stack of running apps.

At first I thought that maybe upon my application being suspended, or maybe Android killing some of my background processes, that variables were being terminated within my program which *might* lead to this kind of behavior, but after looking at the app running with an Android app that observes memory usage and any amount of garbage collection, it doesn't seem like Android is killing anything when this happens.

I have talked to someone else about jQuery Mobile maybe being the culprit (apparently jQuery Mobile acts differently depending on the device platform, and I don't seem to receive these errors on my Nexus 4) and that maybe my page events aren't working correctly?

**My onResume event function (should trigger alert at resume):**

```
    function onResumeApp(){

        //Check to see if there is a suspension time set, if so, check to see if that time has passed, if so, resume normal app behavior
        if(resumeTime != null){

            //in the case of delaying a notification, need to change currentState to active through a timeout function...
            // otherwise causes error in how missing a delayed a notification counts more than once
            if(moment().isAfter(resumeTime)){
                currentState = states.ACTIVE;
                displayAppStatus(states.ACTIVE);
                resumeTime = null;
            }
        }

        if (hasMissedNotification){
            alert("You have missed " + missedNotifications + " random prompt survey(s). Please remember to take as many surveys as possible.");
            hasMissedNotification = false;
            missedNotifications = 0;
        }
        ...
    }
```

Is it okay to navigate to another page upon reading the pause event? In this situation, I could foresee an issue with the app being in the background by the time any code would be read within the pause event listener... then again, why would Phonegap include a pause event function if you can't write any Javascript code to use it?

**My onPause event function:**

```
    function userHasGoneIdle(){


        //If user goes idle and has started a random prompt survey but has not finished it before going idle,
        //Need to record a survey as being abandoned
        if(startedRandomPromptSurvey && !finishedRandomPromptSurvey){

            //If a user delays a notification, don't want to add to missing notifications file yet.
            if(currentState != states.DELAYED){
                hasMissedNotification = true;
                addToMissedNotifications(1, moment().toDate().toString());
                startedRandomPromptSurvey = false;
                finishedRandomPromptSurvey = false;
            }
            //If a user clicks a notification (indicates that they have started a random prompt interview), delays notification,
            //then misses the delayed notificaiton, it will register both an abandoned as well as a missed, when really they have only missed
            //the last delayed notification

        }

        writingToRandomPromptInt = false;
        $("#login-password").val('');

        if(!wakeUpFiring)
            $.mobile.navigate('#login');
        else
            $.mobile.navigate('#wakeup');

        resetSurveyWidgets();

        console.log('userHasGoneIdle');
    }
```

And then I have a bunch of code that is executed by event listener functions by a local notification plugin I use. These events can occur whenever, if the app is in the foreground or the background... they of course do not occur reliably when the app is in the background and I need to change the way this works, but I am wondering if any of the code within these event functions could cause the problem (I want to say yes, because the problems seem to only happen upon accessing the app via notification)

**local notification event functions:**

**ontrigger:**

```
        window.plugin.notification.local.ontrigger = function (id, state, json) {
            console.log('\nontrigger() #' + id + " State: " + state + " @" + moment().toString());// + ' @' + JSON.parse(json).date);

            //if(id != serviceNotificationID){

                if(Math.abs(id >= notificationCount - 1 || notificationCount == 0)){
                    console.log('id - notificationCount == 0:' + id + ' - ' + notificationCount + ' = ' + (id - notificationCount));

                    clearPriorNotifications(function(){
                        addNewNotifications(function(){
                            formNotificationString(writeToNotificationFile);
                        });
                    });
                }

                triggerTime = moment().toDate().toString();

                if(id == 0)
                    didMissDelayedNotification = true;

                if(id != -99){
                    playNotificationAudio();
                }
                //In the case that the user does not access app when an alarm goes off by clicking notification,
                //Have app navigate to wakeup screen
                else{
                    playAlarmAudio();
                    didMissWakeUp = true;
                    wakeUpFiring = true;
                    $.mobile.navigate("#wakeup");
                }

                setTimeout(function(){
                    if(id != -1 && id != -99){
                            //if Havent clicked on a notificaiton, and the notificaiton snt a delayed notificaiton,
                            if(didMissNotificationArr[parseInt(id)] && id != 0){
                                console.log("@onTrigger: didMissNotificationArr[" + id + "] = " + didMissNotificationArr[id]);
                                hasMissedNotification = true;
                                addToMissedNotifications(2, triggerTime);
                                window.plugin.notification.local.cancel(id);
                            }
                            //for missed delayed notifications, only log missed if not clicked and only cancel if not clicked (and therefore cnaceled)
                            else if(id == 0 && didMissDelayedNotification){
                                console.log("@onTrigger: didMissDelayedNotification = " + didMissDelayedNotification);
                                hasMissedNotification = true;
                                addToMissedNotifications(2, triggerTime);
                                window.plugin.notification.local.cancel(id);
                            }

                    }
                    //Need to set boolean to remain at #wakeup, regardless of whether or not the user leaves the app during
                    //wakeup alarm
                    else if(id == -99 && didMissWakeUp){
                        wakeUpFiring = false;
                        window.plugin.notification.local.cancel(id);
                    }
                    else if(id == -1)
                        window.plugin.notification.local.cancel(id);

                }, (180 * 1000));
            //}

        };
```

**onclick:**

```
    window.plugin.notification.local.onclick = function(id, state, json){

            console.log('\n clicking notification #' + id);
            //notificationTime = JSON.parse(json).date;

            //if(id != serviceNotificationID){

                //When clicking on a delayed notification
                if(id == 0){
                    $.mobile.navigate('#delay');
                    didMissDelayedNotification = false;
                    startedRandomPromptSurvey = true;
                    finishedRandomPromptSurvey = false;
                }

                //When clicking on a test notification
                else if(id == -1){
                    $.mobile.navigate("#login");
                    takingTestSurvey = true;
                    startedRandomPromptSurvey = false;
                    finishedRandomPromptSurvey = false;
                }

                //When clicking on a wakeup notification
                else if(id == -99){
                    $.mobile.navigate("#wakeup");
                    startedRandomPromptSurvey = false;
                    finishedRandomPromptSurvey = false;
                }

                //When clicking on a standard, untouched notification
                else{
                    $.mobile.navigate('#delay');
                    startedRandomPromptSurvey = true;
                    finishedRandomPromptSurvey = false;
                    didMissNotificationArr[parseInt(id)] = false;
                }
```

**oncancel:**

```
    window.plugin.notification.local.oncancel = function (id, state, json) {
            console.log('\n CANCELLING notification #' + id + " State: " + state);
            //console.log("caller is " + arguments.callee.caller.toString());

            if(id != -99){
                if(my_media){
                    my_media.stop();
                    //my_media.reset();
                    my_media.release();
                }
            }

            //If wake up alarm notificaiton:
            else{
                wakeUpFiring = false;
                //$.mobile.navigate("#login");
                if(my_alarm_media){
                    my_alarm_media.stop();
                    //my_media.reset();
                    my_alarm_media.release();
                }
            }
        };
```

Any ideas why my app could be unresponsive upon resuming from a notification?

Comment: The App maybe Sleeping, check --- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10366150/how-to-have-an-android-service-keep-the-phonegap-ui-alive --- On how to KeepAlive

Comment: This wake up service listed in this thread could really help me out, as dirty as it is... Thanks!